# Change label when a button has been pressed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, text, uibutton, uilabel

I have a `button` which changes images which it has been pressed, it goes from `img1` to `img2`. I now also want the text to be changed when that certain button been pressed. So it starts on "hello", and then when pressed it turns to "goodbye" for example.

this is my code at the moment:

```
- (void)toggleImage:(UIButton *)btn1 {
    self.btn1ImageName = ([self.btn1ImageName isEqualToString:@"greypad.png"]) ? @"greenpad.png" : @"greypad.png";
    [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.btn1ImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
[self addLabel];
self.btn1ImageName = @"greypad.png";
btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(46, 67, 48, 48)];
[btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.btn1ImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn1];
```

The label?

```
 -(void)addLabel{
        UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, 80)];
        aLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        aLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        aLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        aLabel.text = @"hello";
        [self.view addSubview:aLabel];
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
- (void)toggleImage:(UIButton *)btn1 {
   self.btn1ImageName = ([self.btn1ImageName isEqualToString:@"greypad.png"]) ? @"greenpad.png" : @"greypad.png";
   self.titleStr = ([self.titleStr isEqualToString:@"hello"]) ? @"goodbye" : @"hello";
   [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.btn1ImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [btn1 setTitle:self.titleStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a different approach:

When you set up your button, set different title and image for different states

```
[btn1 setTitle:@"hello" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 setTitle:@"goodbye" forState: UIControlStateSelected];
[btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greypad.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenpad.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

And in your toggle method simply do

```
- (void)toggleImage:(UIButton *)button 
{
    button.selected = !button.selected;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `toggleImage` Method:

```
[bt1 setTitle:@"goodbye" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```